# Determine the size of the data and code segment in hex x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, hex

If I'm looking at an assembly programs `.lst` file (the listing file), how can I determine the size of both the **.data** segment and the **.code** segment?

Would this be determined by the last offset in the segment? For example, here's a listing:

```
 00000000               .data
 00000000 00000019      iX      dword   25,-2,-3 
       FFFFFFFE
       FFFFFFFD
 0000000C 0011 FFFB     sY      word    17,-5,2 dup (17,-4)
       00000002 [
        0011 FFFC
       ]
 00000018  00000003 [       bVal    byte    3 dup(-1,23) ,35
        FF 17
       ] 23
 0000001F 00000015      iNum    dword   21,-43
       FFFFFFD5
 00000027 41 42 43 34 35    bName   byte    "ABC456",29,'DEF'
       36 1D 44 45 46

 00000000               .code
 00000000           _start:
 00000000  B8 00000000          mov eax,0
 00000005  A1 00000002 R        mov  eax, iX[2]
 0000000A  03 05 0000001F R     ADD eax, iNum
 00000010  03 05 00000027 R     ADD eax, dword ptr bName
 00000016  FF 35 0000001F R     PUSH   iNum
 0000001C  FF 35 00000027 R     PUSH dword ptr bName
 00000022  66| 5B           POP   BX
 00000024  5E               POP   ESI
```

Would the size of the data segment be `27h` and the size of the code segment be `24h`?

Comment: The logic is okay, the execution is not :) The **start** offset of the last line of `.data` is indeed `27h` but that contains 10 values, so you need to add that. Similarly with the `.code`, but that only adds 1 byte.

Comment: Okay. I understand the `.data` is 27 + (10*byte) = **37h**, but how do you know that the `POP ESI` line in the code segment only adds 1 byte?

Comment: Nope, `27h+10` is not `37h` because the `10` is in decimal. Since the bytes are listed for every line, it's easy to count them. The `POP ESI` is a single byte with value `5E`.

Comment: Ahh. Could you also just determine the size of the segments using the ESP(stackpointer)-EBP(basepointer)? Or some alternate indirect method, maybe not using the **.lst**? This might be a dumb question but I'm jw.

Comment: No, the stack or the base pointer has nothing to do with it unfortunately. But there are of course other ways, such as common binary formats usually have internal headers giving the sizes, and for currently executing programs you can query the operating system.